# ajax library that populates multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, html, ajax

I'm trying to speed up the data entry for my awards database. My "people" table currently has five fields:

peopleid
first
middle
last
display

So an entry might be:

```
peopleid 120
first    William
middle   H.
last     Macy
display  William H. Macy
```

Is there an AJAX library that you can suggest that would enable someone entering the data to type in the "display" form field and if the name's found it populates the other fields and if not found the person manually enters the name in the correct fields? I've seen some autosuggest libraries but the ones that I've found only seem to deal with the one field.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there are any that have this capability out-of-the-box, but all of the major libraries provide the tools to achieve this in a dozen or two lines of code.

Comment: What libraries would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourite is [dojo Toolkit](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/).  With an XHR request, some JSON generated by your PHP and a form, you could easily accomplish what you are looking for.